# Flexible content area using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a page which is flexible for any device type and resolution. I saw some bootstrap tutorials and built this page from what I learnt from there.

Here is the jsfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/z450vx6x/

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sample Page</title>
<link
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.content {
    background-color: white;
}

.header {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
}

.topnav li{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.topnav  li:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header row-lg-1  row-md-1">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="topnav row-lg-1  row-md-1">
            <ul class="list-inline ">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Product</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="content row-lg-8  row-md-8">
            <strong>What is Lorem Ipsum?</strong>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
                dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
                passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <strong>Why do we use it?</strong>
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The
                point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content
                here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing
                packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
                model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web
                sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
                years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour
                and the like).</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer row-lg-1  row-md-1"
            style="background-color: lightgreen">&#169; ABC Group. All
            Rights Reserved</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My requirements are this:
     1. I need to fix the top level navigation to make the look and feel proper.
     2. Most important issue is how to make the content area stretch to cover the browser height and still be flexible for any device screen.

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad. What problem did you encounter when you attempted "to fix the top level navigation to make the look and feel proper"? What did you try to "make the content area stretch to cover the browser height and still be flexible for any device screen"? Please narrow it down to a single question.

Comment: Ok, the content area is the main issue. Right now, it's height changes based on content. What I want is to have a min height beyond which it will not reduce. and this should not effect the design's capability to free flow based on browser area. I tried setting the area to 70%, but when I load another html using jquery load() method, the div height again goes to 0.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Please specify what you mean by "make it look and feel proper" as there are countless amount of things that can achieve that. Be more specific, do you want it centred, animated differently or something else?

**2.** If the content is too small to cover the entire page then you can't do much other than tweak the padding and margin values to position the content in inner centre and leave enough padding around the content so as for the footer to go lower.

Of course, there are other workarounds for part 2 but since you are at the beginning, I would recommend you to familiarise yourself with margin and padding.

P.S. Since you are using Bootstrap, add additional grid classes (e.g. col-md-X) to your grid div elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Proper look and feel would be the menu content set with proper spacing and on hover the whole section changing color instead of only the text. I am not adding any fix css property to keep the design adaptable to browser size. The content will keep changing based on what options are selected. I want it to be of certain size to accommodate most of the pages I will load in that div. Shall I use min-height? Will having extra padding make the page flexible when more content is added?

Comment: I tried using bootstrap navbar. but that is creating spaces between my header and content components. Not sure how to control the size without making the design static.